# Microsoft speaker recognition api

Tags: api, speaker

In microsoft speaker recognition api what data we have to use for body parameter.
There written as "binary data" . Does this imply that we have to convert audio file to binary data and then paste there.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Currently, it's not possible to use this API testing console for posting application/octet-stream or application/form-data. I believe there's some work on this, and it should be available soon.

As an alternative, you can use [PostMan](https://www.getpostman.com/) or [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler). PostMan might be easier to use. Give it a try and let me know if you have a problem.

Comment: can we use the MS Rec API for live speaker recognition!

Answer (score 1):

The binary data needs to be a WAV file of a specific format:

- Container: WAV
- Encoding: PCM
- Rate: 16K
- Sample Format: 16 bit
- Channels: Mono

You can check out a working example web page over here - I've used an altered copy of `recorderjs` (altered by reverse engineering the Speaker Recognition API examples page) to get the right bit rate and sample rate WAV:

https://rposbo.github.io/speaker-recognition-api/

You could potentially use the test console, since you can send base64 encoded audio data (as the official demo page does):

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/cognitive-services/speaker-recognition/